# Log idf.py monitor to file

Tags: esp32, espressif-idf

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/tools/idf-monitor.html

Indicates CTRL+L will log to a file in the project directory.

Using Windows10 and VSCode, CTRL+L stoops the logging, but I cannot find the file.

Is there a way to log ESP32 monitor output to a file to review later.

`idf.py monitor >> log.txt` does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since you asked the question, but it might still be useful.

You first need to press `CTRL + T` (menu escape key) followed by `CTRL + L`. I am currently using it with ESP-IDF 5.1 and it is working as expected. When you press those key combinations, you should see in the screen a message similar to `Logging is enabled into file log.<project_name>.<timestamp>.txt`.